# How add rownames with no dimensions in R

Tags: r, vector, row, names

```
> Cases <- c(4,46,98,115,88,34)

> Cases
[1]   4  46  98 115  88  34

> str(Cases)
 num [1:6] 4 46 98 115 88 34
```

I want to name row as "total.cases" and I got error attempt to set rownames with no dimensions.please see expected the output to be as follow

```
total.cases 4 46 98 115 88 34
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `Cases` as you define it is an atomic vector. There is no concept of rows or columns.

I think you probably want a list

```
Cases <- list(total.cases = c(4,46,98,115,88,34))
Cases
## $total.cases
## [1]   4  46  98 115  88  34

str(Cases)
## List of 1
##  $ total.cases: num [1:6] 4 46 98 115 88 34
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to print the output in a particular way or do you actually want rownames?

To print `Cases` how you want, you could just use:

```
> cat("total.cases ",Cases,"\n")
total.cases  4 46 98 115 88 34
```

To assign a rowname, you need to actually have rows first. A vector (like `Cases`) doesn't have any rows or columns as dimensions. You could however convert to a matrix though:

```
> matrix(Cases,nrow=1,dimnames=list("total.cases",1:length(Cases)))
            1  2  3   4  5  6
total.cases 4 46 98 115 88 34
```